# Express sendFile breaks

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, filepath, sendfile

I am constantly getting:

```
express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead
```

here is my code:

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {

  var myUrl = req.url.split('/')[1];

  myownfunction(myUrl, function (err, rows) {

    if (rows.length != 0) {
      res.sendfile('views/article.html');
    }
    else
    {
      res.sendfile('views/404.html');
    }
  });
});
```

I changed the `sendfile` to uppercase `sendFile`, but it breaks.
what should i do?

### update

when I run my code:

```
app.get('/upload', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('views/upload_file.html');
});
```

I get this error:
**TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile**

Comment: "it breaks", how does it break? What errors are you getting?

Comment: @BenFortune i updated the question with the error i get: TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile

Comment: did you tried `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"views/upload_file.html"))` (you'll probably need to import nodeJs's path module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **path.join()** function to configure file path.

```
app.get('/upload', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"views/upload_file.html"))
});
```